# How do I get rid of all of these duplicates?

Tags: package-management, icons

Please be gentle, I am new to Linux. I know that everything is handled by package managers like snap, apt, flatpak, etc. but I have no clue which one of these package managers each duplicate app is a part of, so I can't run the command to delete it. There are ways to list the apps, but I have no clue which icon on my Gnome apps corresponds to the listed items in the package manager. From the icons alone, there is no way to right click and have it just tell you "That icon is the snap one." This is important because some of the icons do not work, while some of them do, and some of them are different versions than others. I have duplicates of:

- A bunch of random LibreOffice apps (Idk which one is the new version or the old version. One says 7.3 and the other just says LibreOffice)
- Arduino IDE (one works, one doesn't)
- PPSSPP (One of them has my save data, but I only know it by the app location in the Gnome apps)

If you know of good tutorials to figure out which app is located where in files/package manager, linking that would be chill too. I apologize if this is a dumb question or too simple, I am just really struggling with finding out how to do it. I already know how to list the apps for snap, apt, etc., my struggle is just figuring out which one the app is. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess a good tool for you would be the Synaptic Package Manager. You can install it in most Ubuntu distros with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install synaptic
```

Synaptic basically allows you to manage your packages without using the command line. You can easily check for duplicates and uninstall the obsolete versions.

If that doesn't help, then you should probably do a clean install of each of those apps. The save states for PPSSPP should be in the ~/.config/ppsspp folder, so you can back up before uninstalling.

Comment: Also probably worth mentioning that you don't have to use old versions from the universe repositories or hope that PPA maintainers keep up with new releases (at least in the case of PPSSPP).

Comment: Although OP accepted this answer, it doesn't actually answer the question which was posed. The question boils down to "If I see an icon for an application in my DE, how can I tell which package manager that application was installed with?". There *are* methods for doing that, but this answer instead proposes installing a front-end to APT (just one of the package managers which OP lists), which doesn't help at all with the stated problem.

Comment: Also, although I am sure there are many advantages to Flatpak (but also disadvantages), it's not clear why this answer takes the somewhat unorthodox approach of suggesting that it should be preferred to the distro's built in package managers (in this case APT / Snap). The answer could be improved by elaborating on this, or ideally by removing the suggestion altogether since it is opinion-based and therefore not really suited to this site.

Comment: I do agree that the Flatpak suggestion was out-of-place. I will continue my campaign for ultimate flatpakisation through other means ;) As for answering OP's question, it did look like synaptic could help them with their major issue (a bunch of redundant packages that they were having trouble removing). It seems to have helped. And it's a lot less complicated than delving into the man-pages of apt.

Comment: I still don't see how Synaptic can help with the original issue. E.g., to take one of OP's examples: they have two Arduino IDE icons. One works, one doesn't. OP goes into Synaptic and sees that an Arduino IDE package has been installed. How does that help OP know whether or not removing it will remove the one which doesn't work? In order to do that OP needs some method to identify that the non-working icon relates to an APT-installed package. Worse, if the non-working icon is from another package manager, then Synaptic won't be useful at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the `menulibre` package using Synaptic, Ubuntu Software or via command line:

`$ sudo apt install menulibre`

It provides a nice graphical interface, checks for broken launchers and allows you to view/edit the details for each of the *.desktop files.